# How do I open a new window using ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I need to open a new tab using ClojureScript.

```
(js/window.open "http://localhost/go/somewhere")
```

I get the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: window.open is not a function**

It doesn't help setting it because nothing happens and I assume it is because it is a function and not a variable.

```
(set! js/window.open "http://localhost/go/somewhere")
```

I know it is possible because I got it right initially. I've since forgotten what I've done.

**Edit**: Also tried:

```
(set! js/window.location.open endpoint)

(set! (js/window.location.open -location) endpoint)

(set! (.. js/window.location.open -location) endpoint)
```

Comment: The syntax you are using in your very first attempt is correct. What version of CLJS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your attempts with `set!` you have accidentally "overridden" `window.open` in your browser window; so `window.open` is actually no longer a function, that can be called.

Make sure you don't have a `set!` call before you call `window.open` and reload your page.  The syntax you are using with `(js/window.open ,,,)` is correct.

```clj
(js/window.open "https://example.com") ; works
(set! js/window.open "https://example.com")
(js/window.open "https://example.com")
; ⇒ TypeError: window.open is not a function
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes so much sense. It is working now.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me from a CLJS repl:

```clj
 (.open js/window "https://www.clojure.org")
```

but I had to make sure popups were allowed:

[image]

Comment: That's so odd. I have just tried that and Chrome tells me that it's an **Uncaught TypeError: window.open is not a function**.

Comment: Okay, it works :D @cfrick pointed out the I overrode up my open function when I used `set!`